# How to input range of current values in LT Spice

Tags: current, ltspice, simulation, current-measurement, basic

Firstly, I'm a beginner at LT Spice. I wanted to learn how could you input a range of values for current. For example, let's say, I want my waveform to oscillate from 10uA to 10mA in the circuit below (instead of -10mA to +10mA since I've given 10mA as amplitude)-

[image]

[image]

So, I wanted to know how to change the amplitude for it according to the range I want. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: clarify what you mean by 'oscillate from 10 uA to 10 mA'. Do you mean a sinewave whose +ve peak is +10 mA, and whose -ve peak is + 10 uA, so offset from zero mean? Or do you mean a zero mean sinewave with peaks of +/- 10 mA , whose amplitude can be changed to +/- 10 uA or other values during the simulation?

Comment: Are you asking for the .param and .step SPICE directives?

Answer (score 3):

> *I want my waveform to oscillate from 10uA to 10mA*

That's a peak-to-peak value of 9.99 mA or, a peak value of 4.995 mA.

So, use two current sources in parallel; one set to produce a peak current of 4.995 mA and the other set to deliver the offset current 5.005 mA DC.

Current sources in parallel add and you'll get what you require. Example of a 1 kHz sinewave: -

[image]

[image]

The composite current from the two sources flows into a 1 kΩ resistor and produces a peak of 10 volts and a valley of 10 mV.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a behavioral current source (bi in the components library)

The amplitude could be driven by a voltage source in PWL mode :

[image: PWL example configuration]

and then, the arbitrary current source (or here voltage source) can be configured (you can use the inside variable "time" which is the current time of the simulation)

[image: arbitrary voltage source configuration]

And finally you obtain:

[image: variable sinus voltage]

If you want to modify it over several simulations, I would recommand to look at ".step param *myVariable* list *listOfValue*" in the help

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring only to your current source then what you ened is a sine with offset. So calculate it based on your maximum and minimum values, `(10m + 10u)/2 = 5005u = 5.005m`. Then calculate the amplitude of the sine as `(10m - 10u)/2 = 4995u = 4.995m`, and introduce them in your `SINE()` expression:

```
SINE(5.005m 4.995m 25)
```

The parameters are described in the editor, too:

`SINE(Ioffset Iamp Freq Td Theta Phi Ncycles)`

Not all parameters need to be specified (e.g. you can omit `Td` and all the others, as you have it now).

Also, you have no ground on the primary side. That's a bad habit, even if LTspice tries to avoid you, shooting yourself in the foot, by adding a hidden `Gmin` to ground.